# dygraph tick marks going all the way up to max of valuerange

Tags: dygraphs

I have set the valuerange on of my axis's to [500,1000]

On the corresponding graph there are 6 lines

the bottom line is 500
then 600, 
then 700,
then 800,
then 900,

then there is a line closing off the top of the graph , but there is no "1000" label here. it is just blank.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please provide a demo link, preferably via dygraphs.com/fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aw8Dg/1/

Comment: I have forced the range to be from 0 to 5000 via the code  valueRange:[0,5000], but the graph is not showing a tick for 5000. I am trying to get the top tick mark(preferably the very top of the graph) to show 5000

Comment: Set high range to 5001 and the 500 label appears: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/aw8Dg/2/